# How to empty an std::string?

Tags: c++, iostream

This part of my code runs in an infinite loop and shows a number, but I need to empty the string after the use because, since it run in a loop, its keep being multiplied. (Sorry for my english, it's not my native language)

> text ---> text text ----> text text text

```
cartemap << "Carte: " << currentmap;  //cartemap is a std:string currentmap a integer'

MESSAGE1 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  cartemap.str().c_str() , noir );

apply_surface( 70, 70, MESSAGE1, SCREEN );

SDL_FreeSurface(MESSAGE1);
```

Comment: `str = ""` [morechars]

Comment: `cartemap` is not a `std::string`. `std::string` has no member function named `str`.  It appears to be a `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: `//cartemap is a std:string` --> [Comments are lies](http://johnsy.com/blog/entry/20121031130012)! Perhaps show the declaration next time.

Answer (score 5):

### Answering the question in the title

Call [`std::string::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) to clear a `string`:

```
mystring.clear();
```

### Answering the code in the post

But it looks like you need [`std::ostringstream::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) to clear an *`ostringstream`* (or *`stringstream`*) in your example:

```
cartemap.str("");
```

Comment: It doesnt work it keep being added

Comment: @user3105169: It seems you wish to clear an `ostringstream`, not a `string`. I've updated my answer to accommodate both.

Comment: It worked (second option)

Answer (score 1):

If cartemap is your string, try this:

```
cartemap.resize(0);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/

Comment: It gave me this : 'struct std::stringstream' has no member named 'resize'|

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT from your snippet, `cartemap` is *not* an `std::string`, but it's `std::stringstream` or similar. To empty a string stream, do

```
cartemap.str("");
```

Comment: You<re right! i made an error, i didnt read the stream at the end it passed throught my head... Thank you!